# OrientDB SQL query to emulate a many to many join

Tags: sql, orientdb

Given the following schema created using the OrientDB Document API:

```java
    OClass team = getoDocDatabase().getMetadata().getSchema().createClass(TEAM);
    team.createProperty(NAME, OType.STRING);

    OClass driver = getoDocDatabase().getMetadata().getSchema().createClass(DRIVER);
    driver.createProperty(NAME, OType.STRING);

    OClass car = getoDocDatabase().getMetadata().getSchema().createClass(CAR);
    car.createProperty(NAME, OType.STRING);

    // Relationships
    team.createProperty(CARS_HERITAGE, OType.LINKSET, car);
    car.createProperty(BUILT_BY, OType.LINK, team);
    car.createProperty(DRIVEN_BY, OType.LINKSET, driver);
    driver.createProperty(DRIVER_OF, OType.LINKSET, car);
```

What's the sql query to fetch all the teams that Fernando Alonso has driven for?

In relational SQL would be as easy as

```
SELECT team.name FROM {the join} where driver.name = 'Fernando Alonso'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have try with this db

```
create class Team
CREATE PROPERTY Team.name String

create class DRIVER
CREATE PROPERTY DRIVER.name String

create class Car
CREATE PROPERTY Car.name String

CREATE PROPERTY Team.CARS_HERITAGE LINKSET Car
CREATE PROPERTY Car.BUILT_BY LINK Team
CREATE PROPERTY Car.DRIVEN_BY LINKSET DRIVER
CREATE PROPERTY DRIVER.DRIVER_OF LINKSET Car
```

INSERT

```
INSERT INTO TEAM(name) values ("Ferrari"),("Renault") // Ferrari 12:0  Renault 12:1
insert into Driver(name) values ("Fernando Alonso"),("Giancarlo Fisichella") // Alonso 13:0  Fisichella 13:1
insert into car(name,BUILT_BY,DRIVEN_BY) values ("car ferrari",#12:0,[#13:0,#13:1])
insert into car(name,BUILT_BY,DRIVEN_BY) values ("car renault",#12:1,[#13:0])
```

Query

```
select BUILT_BY.name as TeamName from car where DRIVEN_BY.name contains "Fernando Alonso"
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

UPDATE 1

```
select distinct(BUILT_BY.name) as team from car where DRIVEN_BY.name contains "Fernando Alonso"
```

FROM JAVA API

[image]

UPDATE 2

[image]

FROM JAVA API

[image]

Comment: If `BUILT_BY` is a link, why `BUILT_BY.name` instead of `expand(BUILT_BY).name`?

And the same for `DRIVEN_BY.name`, but in this case it's even harder to understand because it's not a simply a link but a set of links.

Comment: And you should also add a `distinct(expression)` to the select clause to avoid a team to appear more than once in case the driver has driven more than one of its cars.

Comment: If you use expand(BUILT_BY) it expand the document pointed by that link and you get the metadata (@rid,@version,@class) and the field name , while with BUILT_BY.name you get only the property name.

Comment: When using the Java Document API it's strictly needed to use the expand function, so for example, if I want to get all the teams which have cars the query I have to execute is `"SELECT expand(distinct(team)) FROM Car"`. I will commit to github some tests proving it.

Comment: In your update 1 there are 2 things that do not make sense: First, if you select `BUILT_BY.name` the result of the query should be of type String, not Document, and second, even if the result were a Document, when you do `System.out.printl(v.field("team"))` why use the property "team"? If the document is a team the property should be "name", not "team".

Comment: I use "select distinct(BUILT_BY.name) as team  ... " the return field will be called "team" and then I use System.out.printl(v.field("team"))
otherwise when you use "select distinct(BUILT_BY.name) ..."  the  the return field will be called distinct.
If you want you can use "select distinct(BUILT_BY.name) as name ..." and System.out.printl(v.field("name"))(see update 2).

Comment: Right. I had not seen the alias.

Comment: With this schema how would you go about listing all Teams along with the number of cars built by each ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Alessandro is correct, however I've found some weirdnesses in the way the sql is interpreted. Let me explain myself.

I've simplified the goal, let's try to find the query to fetch the teams which have had at least a car.

This first query works, is the one suggested by Alessandro. It returns a list of documents containing one property, that is the name of the team.

```
select distinct(team.name) as name from Car
```

This second query works as well, returning the list of teams (as documents).

```
select expand(distinct(team)) from Car
```

This third query works and returns exactly the same result that the previous, so it ignores the ".name" part of the select.

```
select expand(distinct(team)).name from Car
```

This last query fails. Well it doesn't fail, but it doesn't return what I expected, it returns a list of links to the teams.

```
select distinct(team).name from Car
```

Tests running the queries: [Tests](https://github.com/CompartAG/orientdb-tryouts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/compart/tec/OrientDBQueryF1TeamsIT.java).